# Как разбить столбец на два в SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть следующая задача:

В таблице users в поле name хранятся имя и фамилия пользователя разделенные пробелами.

1. Создайте в таблице два дополнительных поля: first_name и last_name длиной 50 символов.
   Оба поля по умолчанию должны содержать пустую строку.
2. Заполните first_name именами пользователя, а last_name — фамилиями.
   Используйте данные из общего поля name.
3. В конце удалите поле name.

users

| id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Вероника Петрова | 20 |
| 2 | Светлана Иванова | 17 |
| 3 | Елена Абрамова | 18 |
| 4 | Василиса Кац | 15 |
| 5 | Алёна Сорокина | 22 |
| 6 | Алёна Федькова | 28 |
| 7 | Лиана Сорокин | 21 |
| 8 | Карина Белая | 30 |
| 9 | Анастасия Дейчман | 16 |
| 10 | Юлия Фёдорова | 25 |

Использую следующий код:

```
ALTER TABLE users
ADD COLUMN first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
ADD COLUMN last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';

UPDATE users
    SET first_name = LEFT (name, INSTR (' ', name));
    
UPDATE users
    SET last_name = RIGHT (name, INSTR (' ', name));
    
ALTER TABLE users
DROP COLUMN name;
```

Однако столбцы last_name и first_name оказываются пустыми.
Если я правильно понимаю, то они лишь ссылаются на столбец name, но не записывают новые значения.

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы данные сохранялись в last_name и first_name после удаления name?

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: LEFT(name, INSTR (name, ' ') )   и RIGHT (name, LENGTH(name) - INSTR (' ', name));

Comment: Боже, как все было просто оказывается) Только тогда CHAR_LENGTH в данном случае нужен будет. Спасибо Вам!

Answer (score 0):

Лучше применить [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```sql
UPDATE users
SET first_name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', 1),
    last_name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', -1);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0d241fb985c71409ebc5a689d1a3a3ad

Comment: last_name = TRIM(SUBSTR(name, INSTR(name, ' '))); чтобы исключить проблемы с именем в одно слово

Comment: @Konst Неизвестно, есть ли такие записи вообще... судя по вопросу, это вообще учебное задание, и все записи корректны - нет ни значений в одно слово или из более чем двух слов, ни ведущих/концевых/двойных пробелов. PS. А если в середине слова обнаружится какое-нить эмодзи, так всё вообще станет весело и забавно.

Comment: согласен, вероятно это просто учебное задание